# любая переменная не перезаписывается, если объявить функцию перезаписи в ng-click блоку вместе с ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Здравствуйте. Надеюсь смогу нормально объяснить проблему. Дело в том, что у меня создаются блоки через ng-repeat и так же на каждый из блоков я вешаю ng-click:

```
<div class="divsStyles, userDiv" ng-repeat="user in usersData | filter:filterID" ng-click="confirmationToRequestToTolkFunction(user)">
```

эта функция должна записывать данные usera в переменную в контроллере(либо $scope либо var любую), но очень странноё поведение. Если выводит аллер внутри функции она показывает что переменная перезаписалась (либо это совершенно новая только-что создалась в функции), но на выходе всеравно ничего не меняется. Я попробовал навешать такой же ng-click на совершенно другой блок который создается без ng-repeat и тогда все отлично работает(конечно на нем нет usera и я просто записываю другое значение, но на ng-reteat я тоже пробовал и там ни в какую не меняется). С чем может быть связанно такое поведение?

Comment: У каждого элемента в ng-repeat свой собственный $scope.

Comment: как тогда я могу перезаписать $scope контроллера?